# Vim: is there a fast way to go from three horizontal windows to one vertical and two horizontal?

Tags: vim, window

Suppose you have three windows open each with a different file. Let's call the files one two and three. The windows are vertical like so:

[image: Vim with three vertical windows]

Is there a fast way to go from three vertical windows to one vertical on the left side and the other two stacked horizontally on the right side? Like this:

[image: Vim with one vertical window and two horizontal]

I currently go the far right window, do a horizontal split explicitly giving the name of the middle buffer file, then move to the middle window and quit. There has to be an easier way, right?

Answer (score 0):

> do a horizontal split explicitly giving the name of the middle buffer file

You can reduce your typing by using `:h alternate-file`: if your buffer#2 happens to be alternate for buffer#3 then you can split by <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> and then switch to alternate buffer by <kbd>Ctrl-6</kbd>. And even if it's not you can still do <kbd>2</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-6</kbd> (note that here 2 is buffer number, not window number).

Answer (score 0):

I would…

1. move the cursor to the rightmost window:

   ```
   <C-w>b
   ```
2. close it:

   ```
   <C-w>q
   ```
3. split the current window to buffer `three`:

   ```
   :sb three<CR>
   ```

See `: help ctrl-w_b`, `:help ctrl-w_q`, `:help :sbuffer`.